# multi level parameters to rest post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

How do I pass multilevel parameters to POST when I'm using net/http library?

example that works:

```
require "net/http"

http = Net::HTTP.new("localhost", 3000)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/external/rd")
request.set_form_data({:name => 'device_rb'})
response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

but common rails notation would be:

```
"device" => {:name => 'device_rb'}
```

I have no idea how to put this embeded parameters to set_form_data method. Any help?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are posting form data, your data will get encoded in [x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#current-value) format. This is more or less a simple key/value format with no nesting of structures.

If you want nesting for the data you pass to the server, you would have to use a format that allows it, such as JSON or XML. You cannot set the payloads for these formats with `set_form_data` though.

You rather set them using `request.body = payload`. See also this [simple example](https://www.socialtext.net/open/very_simple_rest_in_ruby_part_3_post_to_create_a_new_workspace) for posting a JSON payload.

Comment: not exactly that. When I use your approach I still see server log like:

  Parameters: {"name"=>"device_json", "operating_system_id"=>"7", "hash_string"=>"jfsg3k4ovj0j02jv", "user_id"=>"1"}

when I want to see sometging like: 

  Parameters: {"app"=>{"name"=>"blabla", "device_id"=>"6", "type_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create App"}

difference is in controller later. Using your (and mine) approach I need to use:

'@obj.name = params[:name]
@obj.smth = params[:smth]'

and I want to use:

'@obj = params[:obj]'

Comment: OK, done with nested values: '@device = {
"device" => {
  "name" => "device_json", 
  "operating_system_id" => "7", 
  "hash_string" => "jfsg3k4ovj0j02jv", 
  "user_id" => "1"
}
}.to_json'